# Passing DataContext into Action()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Instead of doing:

```
 using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
 {
   //do something
 }
```

I'd like to use an Action()

```
public static class SimpleUsing
{
  public static void DoUsing(Action action)
  {
    using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
    {
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Which would be used as

```
SimpleUsing.DoUsing(() =>
{
   //but how to get DataContext variable?
}
```

The main issue is how do I access the "db" variable to make use of the DataContext?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generic types `Action<T1>`, `Action<T1, T2>`, etc. define a delegate which takes some arguments.  So you can write it like this:

```
public static class SimpleUsing
{
    public static void DoUsing(Action<MyDataContext> action)
    {
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
           action(db);
    }

    public static T DoUsing(Func<MyDataContext, T> fn)
    {
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
           return fn(db);
    }
}

// ...

SimpleUsing.DoUsing(db => {
    // do whatever with db
});

var result = SimpleUsing.DoUsing(db => {
    return 42; // uses Func overload, result will be 42
});
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  Do you know how I may be able to return a type from this?  That makes DoUsing a generic method (return some T).

Comment: I believe you have to use a Func<> to return a value.

Comment: @TGnat, do you have some idea what that looks like?  It will have to come out of action and pass back to the method.