# How to return value from Action()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In regards to the answer for this question [Passing DataContext into Action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098950/passing-datacontext-into-action), how do I return a value from action(db)?

```
SimpleUsing.DoUsing(db => { 
// do whatever with db 
});
```

Should be more like:

```
MyType myType = SimpleUsing.DoUsing<MyType>(db => { 
// do whatever with db.  query buit using db returns MyType.
});
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Your static method should go from:

```
public static class SimpleUsing
{
    public static void DoUsing(Action<MyDataContext> action)
    {
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
           action(db);
    }
}
```

To:

```
public static class SimpleUsing
{
    public static TResult DoUsing<TResult>(Func<MyDataContext, TResult> action)
    {
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
           return action(db);
    }
}
```

This answer grew out of comments so I could provide code.  For a complete elaboration, please see @sll's answer below.

Answer (score 143):

You can use `Func<T, TResult>` generic delegate. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx))

```
Func<MyType, ReturnType> func = (db) => { return new MyType(); }
```

Also there are useful generic delegates which considers a return value:

- `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx))
- `Predicate<TInput>` -  always return bool ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx))

---

**Method:**

```
public MyType SimpleUsing.DoUsing<MyType>(Func<TInput, MyType> myTypeFactory)
```

**Generic delegate:**

```
Func<InputArgumentType, MyType> createInstance = db => return new MyType();
```

**Execute:**

```
MyType myTypeInstance = SimpleUsing.DoUsing(
                            createInstance(new InputArgumentType()));
```

**OR explicitly:**

```
MyType myTypeInstance = SimpleUsing.DoUsing(db => return new MyType());
```

Comment: Right - can you provide an example of what the method should look like?

Comment: I sitll don't follow how this fits in.  Can you show it with the method signature (i.e. public static void DoUsing(Action action))?    @L.B: yes - my post is the result.

Comment: @L.B -- asking people to google is not constructive.  SO exists to provide complete answers.

Comment: @4thSpace, the problem is that `SimpleUsing.DoUsing` is written to consume an `Action` -- it needs to be overloaded to *also* support `Func`.

Comment: @KirkWoll But the answer gives the **ingredients**, it doesn't have be **cooked**

Comment: @L.B. -- it's better for it to be complete.  I find your analogy spurious.

Comment: @Kirk, it doesn't need to consume Action.  That's just what I started with.  The answer from the previous solution is what I need.  But now I need it to return a Type I provide, however that solution should look.  That's where I'm at now.

Comment: @L.B, better to not comment since you aren't adding any value what so ever.

Comment: This did not answer the question. He is looking for how to return a value from an action delegate, not func delegate...

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev - you're right but Action is not a facility to return a value, surely we can turn around and reinvent the wheel but does such code complication worth sticking principally to Action?

Answer (score 28):

Use [`Func<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) rather than [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8).

[`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) acts like a void method with parameter of type T, while [`Func<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) works like a function with no parameters and which returns an object of type T.

If you wish to give parameters to your function, use `Func<TParameter1, TParameter2, ..., TReturn>`.

Answer (score 15):

You can also take advantage of the fact that a lambda or anonymous method can close over variables in its enclosing scope.

```
MyType result;

SimpleUsing.DoUsing(db => 
{
  result = db.SomeQuery(); //whatever returns the MyType result
}); 

//do something with result
```

Comment: yeah, this is called Closure (funcitonal language stuff which is available for us as well)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ssls answer: For a software we call a lot of "micro methods" to query this and that from the local machine. Sometimes exceptions appear (file / folder not existing, etc). In order to not repeat our self over and over with try/catch blocks, we used ssls approach with return values:

```
private T ExecuteAndCatch<T>(Func<T> action, T defaultReturn)
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Exception during ExecuteAndCatch", ex);
        return defaultReturn;
    }
}
```

Example of mentioned micro-methods:

```
private Boolean CheckKasperskyInstalled() => System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%pf_x86%\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Windows\avp.exe"));
private Boolean CheckKasperskyRunning() => System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("avp").Length > 0;
```

And when using, we no longer have to care if these Methods might throw an exception for whatever reason:

```
cci = new ComputerComplianceInfo();
cci.KasperskyInstalled = ExecuteAndCatch(() => CheckKasperskyInstalled(), false);
cci.KasperskyRunning = ExecuteAndCatch(() => CheckKasperskyRunning(), false);
```